# Two elements highlight themselves and eachother

Tags: html, css

There are two elements. When I highlight on either element, I would like for them **both** to phase in. I attempted to use the general sibling operator (~) to accomplish this. However, it appears that this will only work for one case. The problem is illustrated on [my website](http://chrismunroe.pw). When you hover over the word of the day element it is the only one that is highlighted. This sibling operator appears to only work on elements declared after foo in the html for a sibling tag like `div.foo ~ .bar` how would I do this backwards?

## CSS for phasing

```
div.lisWrap:hover ~.wordSpace, .lisWrap:hover{ //works
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

div.wordSpace:hover ~.lisWrap, .wordSpace:hover{ //doesnt work
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do it backwards in a conventional way. If the area of the parent element consists only of those two elements, you could cheat by having a hover style on the parent element instead. Otherwise you will need JavaScript.

Comment: use jQuery or javascript

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you for the suggestion. I will apply these CSS properties to a parent div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

In CSS you cannot address to a previous or parent elements. It's a kind of a law.

The better way is to fetch :hover on element that contains both of your elements.